# Inverting the matrix $\eta_{uv}(p^2-i\epsilon)-(1-\frac{1}{x})p_u p_v$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory, linear-algebra, propagator

In Weinberg Quantum Theory of Fields Volume 2, p.23, it says that $\eta_{uv}(p^2-i\epsilon)-(1-\frac{1}{x})p_u p_v$ where $0 <x \leq 1$ has the inverse matrix $[\eta_{uv}+(x-1)\frac{p_u p_v}{p^2}]/(p^2-i\epsilon)$.

I cannot understand this calculation. Is it an approximation, or an exact result? I especially cannot see why $-(1-1/x)$ can be transformed into $x-1$. Could anyone please explain?

Comment: You can write Greek indices as \mu and \nu rather than resorting to u and v.

Comment: So I multiply the two tensors and check that it gives the identity matrix?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Multiply them like matrices so that two of the four indices are contracted.

Comment: And may ignore the terms proportional to $\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, in QFT these epsilons are infinitesimal.

Comment: You can use the tensors corresponding to transverse and longitudinal projections, write the matrix as a sum of those projections, and then you can easily invert. E.g., how would you invert the 2x2 matrix $a|0><0|+b|1><1|$, for $a, b\neq 0$?